# How should I interpret　どうなりたっかたんだろう

Tags: translation

Can someone help figure out how the sentence in the title post can be translated? The full sentence is
私はどうなりたっかたんだろう.

I loosely translated as "I wanted to become something". but I'm not sure if it's right at all, especially with だろう at the end, I don't know what nuance should be. If it helps, there's another sentence that follows
本当は彼らの何になりたっかたんだろう
It's a girl speaking here and I think that in the last line she says "I wanted to become something for him/ or his something". She is talking about a friend who is in trouble and how she wants to be there for him.
Can someone tell me if I somehow got the gist of them? Thank you!

Comment: なりた**っか**たんだろう should be a typo for なりた**かっ**たんだろう

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(の/ん)だろう [has various meanings](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/jlpt-n5-grammar-%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86-darou/). When it is used with interrogatives like いつ, どこ, なぜ, it adds the nuance of "I wonder".

> - なぜだろう? I wonder why?
> - どこでやっているんだろう? I wonder where it's taking place.

So 私はどうなりたかったんだろう is "I wonder who I wanted to become."

> - 私はパイロットになりたい。 I want to become a pilot.
> - 私はパイロットに**なりたかった**。 I **wanted** to become a pilot.
> - 私は**どう**なりたかった**か**？ Who did I want to become?
> - 私はどうなりたかった**んだろう**？ **I wonder** who I wanted to become.

どうなる actually means "how (something/someone) turns out to be", but I think using "who" is enough.

彼らの何になりたかったんだろう is trickier because 彼らの何 is difficult to translate literally:

> - 彼らの友人になりたい。 I want to become their friends.
> - 彼らの友人になりたかった。 I wanted to become their friends.
> - 彼らの**何**になりたかった**のか**？ Who, from their standpoint, did I want to become?
> - 彼らの何になりたかった**のだろう**？ I wonder who did I want to become for them?

Comment: Thank you so much! It's much clearer now! And yeah, the second sentence might have sounded a bit weird but now, from the 4th example, I think that is the best translation. Thank you so much! It was really helpful.